# What is the best way to iterate through with c#?

Tags: c#

I have a file with data. 
Here is the link:
https://pastebin.com/Brbug5MD

The task is to iterate through, and add the values of the third column (starts with 1-0-0..3..11..). 34 is the total sum.

What is the best way to do it? I am beginner in c#, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                   string line;
        int sum = 0;
        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
           new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\temp\test.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] delimiters = new char[] { '|' };
            string[] arr = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) break;
            Console.WriteLine(arr[2]);

            sum += Int32.Parse(arr[2]);

        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
        file.Close();
    }
```

I get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

{"Index was outside the bounds of the array."} What I am doing wrong?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service. Post the applicable code with a specific problem, and you are much more likely to get needed help.

Comment: Some helpful functions would be `File.ReadAllLines(string)`, `String.Split(char [])`, and `foreach`

Comment: yes, sorry. I added the code

Comment: and the exception as well.

Comment: It's because your last line doesn't have enough columns.

Comment: how to "stop" the sum when the compiler is in the last column?

Comment: Here's a one liner: `File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\test.txt").Select(l => l.Split(new string[]{"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None)).Where(s => s.Length > 2).ToArray().Select(v => int.Parse(v[2])).Sum()`.  What this does is it reads all the lines, splits it by the pipe character, checks to see if there are more than 2 columns, selects the 3rd column as an int, and sums it up.

Comment: To change your existing code, simply check `arr.Length` > 2 and `continue` if false.

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

```
string line;
int sum = 0;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] arr = line.split("|"); // split the line into an array
   sum += Int32.Parse(arr[2]); // get the 3rd element in the row an convert it to int
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: there is an error with the split. I changed to line.Split(new string[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None); but isnt working neither

Comment: try casting line to a string. so (string)line.split("|")

Comment: how about you use this as a starting point and look for other resources on the internet that will help you understand how to split strings in C#. Expecting stack overflow to just do all the work for you is rude.